# Angular with underscore in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, angular, underscore.js

I have a underscore template in wordpress.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-load-profile">
    <div class="title">{{angular module name here}}</div>
    <img src="{{data.thumbnail}}">
</script>
```

Now the point is the underscore and angular have the same syntax.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: underscore template? underscore doesn't have curley braces tag..

Comment: Have you experience with wordpress underscore ?

Comment: In wordpress the underscore template syntax is {{ data }} . I know the actual syntax is ._ for underscore.